# TypeError: verifyJsonWebToken is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I created two model (I use MongoDB):

User: name, email, password, isBanned, blogPosts[].

BlogPost: title, content, date, author.

with author: {type:ObjectId, ref: 'User'}

I want insert a new blog post with Json Web Token. But I received error: : TypeError: verifyJWT is not a function

Here is my code:

```
const { verifyJWT } = require('./User')
const insertBlogPost = async (title, content, tokenKey) => {
try {
    //Check Login with tokenKey
    let signedInUser = await verifyJWT(tokenKey) //<-Code not run here
    let newBlogPost = await BlogPost.create({
        title, content,
        date: Date.now(),
        author: signedInUser
    })
    await newBlogPost.save()
    await signedInUser.blogPosts.push(newBlogPost._id)
    await signedInUser.save()
    return newBlogPost
} catch(error) {        
    throw error
}}
module.exports = {
BlogPost,
insertBlogPost,
}
```

Here's verifyJWT from User

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const verifyJWT = async (tokenKey) => {
try {          
    let decodedJson = await jwt.verify(tokenKey, secretString)
    if(Date.now() / 1000 >  decodedJson.exp) {
        throw "Token timeout, please Login again"
    }
    let foundUser = await User.findById(decodedJson.id)
    if (!foundUser) {
        throw "Can not find user with this token"
    }
    if(foundUser.isBanned === 1) {
        throw "User looked"
    }
    return foundUser
} catch(error) {
    throw error
}}
module.exports = { User, verifyJWT }
```

And here's my router:

```
router.post('/insertBlogPost', async (req, res) =>{
let {title, content} = req.body
//Client must send tokenKey
let tokenKey = req.headers['x-access-token']
try {
    let newBlogPost = await insertBlogPost(title, content, tokenKey)
    res.json({
        result: 'ok',
        message: 'Create BlogPost successfully!',
        data: newBlogPost
    })
} catch(error) {
    res.json({
        result: 'failed',
        message: `${error}`
    })
}})
```

Github: https://github.com/vantuan1303/authentication

Comment: are you exporting your function `verifyJWT` from user.js

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already use: module.exports = {
    User, 
    verifyJWT
} in model User

Comment: To avoid such confusion, Please add complete code.

Comment: @NguyenVanTuan, i think you must do like this const { verifyJWT } = require('./User').verifyJWT

Comment: Looks good to me. Should not throw an error. Weird.

Comment: I already upload Github at link: https://github.com/vantuan1303/authentication
I don't know why I take a error.